# Why am I getting the ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT a.ID,
SUM (A.AMT) AS AMT,
RANK ()
OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.NO DESC)
AS rnk
FROM TBL1  A 
JOIN TBL2 B
ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.DATE <= a.DATE
 WHERE     b.CD = 'AB'
AND a.DESC = 'P'
AND a.TYP_DESC = 'SEC'
AND a.actg_prd_id between (TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('&&DATE','YYMM'),-2),'YYMM')) and '&&DATE'
group by a.ID
) a
 WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

Can Someone please help me with this query. When I run it without the "SUM" the query works fine, but as soon as I try to SUM the AMT field, my group by expression is not working right and I keep getting an error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression".

Comment: You are using `b.NO` in SELECT but not grouping by  `b.NO` in GROUP BY. Depending on your goal drop `b.NO` from SELECT or add to GROUP BY.

Comment: Please explain what you want to accomplish.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Comment: @MTO, I am essentially bringing in a set population for a specific time period. The RNK is there in order to remove Duplicate records. I'm simply deriving the population with all the expressions in the where clause and pulling in the AMT value for each records in the population. I can get this easily, the issue is when I try to Sum up the AMT, the Group by is not working properly.

Comment: Why do you think you will have duplicate values? If you want to ignore the duplicates **before** aggregating then you need to filter first and then aggregate second. If you want to ignore duplicates **after** aggregating then you do not need to worry as you will not have any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

`RANK` is an analytic function and not an aggregation function and you are using `b.NO` without aggregation inside it so it is raising the exception.

Either do not use unaggregated values inside the `RANK` or remove the `RANK` function.

---

However, using `RANK` with that `PARTITION BY` clause would not do much since you `GROUP BY a.ID` then the query will aggregate and return only a single row for each `a.ID` value. Given that you are `PARTITION BY a.ID` in the `RANK` analytic function and there will only ever be one row for each `a.ID` from the aggregation then you will never get a `RANK` value above `1` and can just use:

```sql
SELECT a.ID,
       SUM (A.AMT) AS AMT,
       1 AS rnk
FROM   TBL1  A 
       JOIN TBL2 B
       ON a.ID = b.ID AND b."DATE" <= a."DATE"
WHERE  b.CD = 'AB'
AND    a."DESC" = 'P'
AND    a.TYP_DESC = 'SEC'
AND    a.actg_prd_id between TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('&&DATE','YYMM'),-2),'YYMM') and '&&DATE'
GROUP BY a.ID
```

---

If you are attempting to find the `SUM(a.AMT)` row with the lowest value then you need to remove the `PARTITION BY` clause and use `RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM(a.AMT) )`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.ID,
         SUM (A.AMT) AS AMT,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(A.AMT)) AS rnk
  FROM   TBL1  A 
         JOIN TBL2 B
         ON a.ID = b.ID AND b."DATE" <= a."DATE"
  WHERE  b.CD = 'AB'
  AND    a."DESC" = 'P'
  AND    a.TYP_DESC = 'SEC'
  AND    a.actg_prd_id between TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('2101','YYMM'),-2),'YYMM') and '2101'
  GROUP BY a.ID
)
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32d4b450bd5b898c5daf3e057a2719a7)*

Comment: The RANK is there purely to remove duplicate records.

Comment: @ace123 You will not have any duplicate records after aggregating.